Canonical epimorphisms vs Projections vs Idempotents
In the context of linear algebra, a projection $P$ from $V\cong \mathbb{R}^n$ onto $S \cong \mathbb{R}^m$ is an $n \times n$ idempotent matrix (i.e. $P^2=P$) such that image of $P$ is $S$. In a more abstract setting, $\pi: V \to S$ is defined to be canonical epimorphism. Now, if $\iota: S \to V$ is an injection, $\iota\pi$ can be identified by matrix $P$.
The map $\pi$ is also defined as a projection. My questions are how do we usually determine that by projection we mean an idempotent map or a canonical epimorphism, and what are the differences among projections, natural projections, and canonical projections?
To give you my context, let $(\mathbb{R}^n, \rho)$ be an orthogonal representation with a subrepresentation $(\mathbb{R}^m, \rho')$. I want to define two objects: an $n \times n$ idempotent matrix $P$ which is the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and an $n \times m$ matrix $p^T$ whose columns are formed by the elements of the basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that span $\mathbb{R}^m$. In my context, I work with both matrices and operators. Which name should I pick to distinguish $P$ and $p$?
I am thinking to refer $P$ as an orthogonal projection and $p$ as an orthogonal epimorphism. What do you think? Do we have "orthogonal epimorphism"?
The other idea that I have is to refer to $P$ as an orthogonal projection and $p$ as a natural orthogonal projection, or $P$ as an orthogonal idempotent and $p$ as a natural orthogonal projection.
What are your suggestions?
